# Auto-schema for time-partitioned tables in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to append data to a time-partitioned table. We can create a time-partitioned table as follows:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# dataset_ref = client.dataset('my_dataset')

table_ref = dataset_ref.table('my_partitioned_table')
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('post_abbr', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('date', 'DATE')
]
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
    type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
    field='date',  # name of column to use for partitioning
    expiration_ms=7776000000)  # 90 days

table = client.create_table(table)

print('Created table {}, partitioned on column {}'.format(
    table.table_id, table.time_partitioning.field))
```

I was wondering however do to the following without pre-defining the schema as I am looking for a generic way to append new data.

When I remove the schema in the example above I get the error that a time partioned table requires a pre-defined schema. However, my files have changed over time meaning that I cannot and do no not want to redefine my schema (I will use Google DataPrep to clean it afterwards).

How I can solve it?

Comment: You MUST at least have the time partition field as part of your schema and if you want to change the other fields you can you 1 array field to store the data and use on the select unnest and array functions to select and process your data

Answer (score 0):

You can update the schema of table when you append new data into it. The two supported schema updates are adding new fields and relaxing a required filed to optional. Search for schemaUpdateOptions [this help page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs):